# rxjs/Subscription has no exported member 'ISubscription'

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm migrating from angular 5 to angular 6. When I make npm run build, I'm it is throw to the console the following error:

> ngc compilation failed: ng-formly/core/src/components/formly.field.ts(10,10): error TS2305: Module '"C:/PrjNET/Elevation3/FW/4.00/Mainline/Framework/Development/Client/ElevationJS/ngcore/.tmp/node_modules/rxjs/Subscription"' has no exported member 'Subscription'.

I had a similar error: `rxjs/Subscription has no exported member Subscription` and I solve by importing Subscription like this:

```
import { Subscription } from "rxjs";
```

But I cannot do the same to `ISubscription`.

Any one knows how can import ISubscription ?

Comment: It's `SubscriptionLike`, now.

Comment: @cartant Can you put this as an answer?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In RxJS v6, `ISubscription` was renamed to `SubscriptionLike`, as that's the convention used in Typescript's own type declarations.

Similarly, `IScheduler` was renamed to `SchedulerLike`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think u can use the `ISubscription` interface directly. If you check the `Subscription.d.ts`, it doesn't have a `declare` type for that interface. I think You have to use the `Subscription` since it's implementing the `ISubscription` interface.